# wander & chase AI code not working

Tags: c#, xna, artificial-intelligence, behavior

Put together an enemy AI system for an enemy in which it should wander around idly when the player is not within distance to the enemy and when player is within enemy distance it should initiate chase behaviour and chase after player until player has managed to exit out of the enemy's chase radius.

Currently the enemy is able to wonder freely yet when the player comes within proximity of the enemy the enemy will carry on wandering instead of chasing player.

Anyone help me fix this problem?

Code is as follows.

```
public enum AIState
    {
        Chasing,           
        Wander
    }

    private float maxSpeed;
    private float maxRotation;
    private float chaseDistance; 
    private float hysteresis;

    private Texture2D texture;
    private Vector2 drawingOrigin;
    private Vector2 position;
    public AIState aiState = AIState.Wander;
    private float orientation;

    private Random random = new Random();
    private Rectangle viewportbounds;
    public Rectangle boundingBox;
    public Vector2 playerPosition;

    private Vector2 heading;


    public Virtual_Aliens(Rectangle pos, Rectangle b)
    {


        position = new Vector2(300, 400);

        boundingBox = new Rectangle(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Width, pos.Height);

        viewportbounds = new Rectangle(b.X, b.Y, b.Width, b.Height);

        orientation = 0.0f;

        heading = new Vector2(0, 0);

        maxSpeed = 2.0f;

        maxRotation = 0.20f;

        hysteresis = 15.0f;

        chaseDistance = 250.0f;

        Thread.Sleep(200);

        random = new Random();

    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("images/asteroid");
    }

    private Vector2 OrientationAsVector(float orien)
    {
        Vector2 orienAsVect;

        orienAsVect.X = (float)Math.Cos(orien);
        orienAsVect.Y = (float)Math.Sin(orien);

        return orienAsVect;
    }

    Vector2 wanderPosition = new Vector2();

    public void Wander()
    {
        // the max +/- the agent will wander from its current position
        float wanderLimits = 0.5f;

        // this defines what proportion of its maxRotation speed the agent will turn
        float turnFactor = 0.15f;

        // randomly define a new position
        wanderPosition.X += MathHelper.Lerp(-wanderLimits, wanderLimits, (float)random.NextDouble());
        wanderPosition.Y += MathHelper.Lerp(-wanderLimits, wanderLimits, (float)random.NextDouble());

        if (wanderPosition != Vector2.Zero)
        {
            wanderPosition.Normalize();
        }

        orientation = TurnToFace(wanderPosition, orientation, turnFactor * maxRotation);

        heading = OrientationAsVector(orientation);

        position += heading * 0.5f * maxSpeed;

        WrapForViewport();
    }

    private void WrapForViewport()
    {
        if (position.X < 0)
        {
            position.X = viewportbounds.Width;
        }
        else if (position.X > viewportbounds.Width)
        {
            position.X = 0;
        }

        if (position.Y < 0)
        {
            position.Y = viewportbounds.Height;
        }
        else if (position.Y > viewportbounds.Height)
        {
            position.Y = 0;
        }
    }

    private float WrapAngle(float radian)
    {
        while (radian < -MathHelper.Pi)
        {
            radian += MathHelper.TwoPi;
        }
        while (radian > MathHelper.Pi)
        {
            radian -= MathHelper.TwoPi;
        }
        return radian;
    }

    private float TurnToFace(Vector2 steering, float currentOrientation, float turnSpeed)
    {
        float newOrientation;
        float desiredOrientation;
        float orientationDifference;

        float x = steering.X;
        float y = steering.Y;

        // the desiredOrientation is given by the steering vector
        desiredOrientation = (float)Math.Atan2(y, x);

        // find the difference between the orientation we need to be
        // and our current Orientation
        orientationDifference = desiredOrientation - currentOrientation;

        // now using WrapAngle to get result from -Pi to Pi 
        // ( -180 degrees to 180 degrees )
        orientationDifference = WrapAngle(orientationDifference);

        // clamp that between -turnSpeed and turnSpeed.
        orientationDifference = MathHelper.Clamp(orientationDifference, -turnSpeed, turnSpeed);

        // the closest we can get to our target is currentAngle + orientationDifference.
        // return that, using WrapAngle again.
        newOrientation = WrapAngle(currentOrientation + orientationDifference);

        return newOrientation;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {            
        if (aiState == AIState.Wander)
        {
            chaseDistance -= hysteresis / 2;
        }

        else if (aiState == AIState.Chasing)
        {
            chaseDistance += hysteresis / 2;    
        }

        float distanceFromPlayer = Vector2.Distance(position, playerPosition);

        if (distanceFromPlayer > chaseDistance)
        {     
            aiState = AIState.Wander;
        }
        else
        {
            aiState = AIState.Chasing;
        }

        float currentSpeed;

        if (aiState == AIState.Chasing)
        {
            orientation = TurnToFace(playerPosition, orientation, maxRotation);
            currentSpeed = maxSpeed;
        }
        else if (aiState == AIState.Wander)
        {
            Wander();
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        boundingBox.X = (int)position.X;
        boundingBox.Y = (int)position.Y;

        drawingOrigin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, boundingBox, null, Color.White, orientation, drawingOrigin, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
    }

    public Vector2 PlayerPosition
    {
        set
        {
            playerPosition = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return playerPosition;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why did you put `Thread.Sleep(200);` ?

Comment: woops didn't mean to have that in there, that was from code I used in the past it basically that if I did a second alien in the main game logic that it would set a another random point for the alien else they would both mimic their movements

Answer (score 0):

You get the distance from the player using:

```
float distanceFromPlayer = Vector2.Distance(position, playerPosition);
```

But you never actually set the variable playerPosition in your class. So effectively if the enemy is within the chase radius from the point (0,0) they will chase your player, but otherwise will they will just wander around.

I would recommend doing one of two things to solve this issue.

First off you could change the parameters of your Update method to take in the Vector2 of the players position.

A second approach (the one I would personally choose) would be to add a new field (class variable) that is of type Player and then in your Virtual_Aliens' constructor pass in an instance of the player class. That way any time you reference playerPosition you would be able to just say player.Position (or however you have your position field named).

Comment: Surely the get set method I put at bottom would do the same as this as  in the main game logic I would simply put in the loadcontent section

    `Vector2 playerPosition;`
    `player.position = playerPosition;`

as I then in the main game logic I can call the main player through `private Player mainPlayer = new Player();`

Comment: Also sorry the method you mention I tried to no avail, the enemy will still wonder but when the player gets close to enemy it doesn't start chasing the player.